# Sum of n-amount of Integers Scanner

Tags: java

I have to enter an unknown amount of numbers using a scanner. Once the user enters -1, the program needs to print the sum of all the numbers entered and then end the program. The -1 needs to be included in the sum.

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
int sum = 0;               

while (true) {
  int read = scanner.nextInt();
  if (read == -1) {
    break;
  }

 read = scanner.nextInt();
 sum += read;
}

System.out.println(sum);
```

I can't get the correct sum. Can someone help please?

Comment: Remove that second `read = scanner.nextInt();` from your loop. You're basically reading 2 integers from the console but ignore the first one. Also move the `sum += read;` up before the check to include the -1 in the sum (don't do that if that shouldn't happen).

Comment: Can you give us an example of what sum you get instead of the expected result?

Comment: I would enter the numbers 14 11 19 9 -1. My answer ends up being 20.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your while loop you're assigning `read` two times using `scanner.nexInt()` and this breaks your logic.

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
int sum = 0;               

while (true) {
    int read = scanner.nextInt();
    if (read == -1) {
        sum += read; //have to include -1 to sum
        break;
    }

    //read = scanner.nextInt(); you have to delete this line

    sum += read;
}

System.out.println(sum);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
int sum = 0;               
int read = 0;
while (read != -1) {
   read = scanner.nextInt();
   sum += read;
}
scanner.close();
System.out.println(sum);
```

This works in my case.
Closing the scanner will remove the warning too.

Answer (score 0):

The following program will add -1 also in your sum. You are reading    `read = scanner.nextInt();` two times.

```
 Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        int sum = 0;               

        while (true) {
            int read = scanner.nextInt();


            sum += read;
            if (read == -1) {
                break;
            }
        }

        System.out.println(sum);
    }
```

Comment: @Thomas "The -1 needs to be included in the sum." By OP

Comment: @THess yes, saw that now :)